# display="table-cell" for vertical alignment doesn't work

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, css-position

I try to use `display="table-cell"` and `vertical-align="middle"` to display the date, the name and the edit link next to the avatar in comments.php in wordpress.

That's the code I'm using:

```css
.commentlist {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}
.comment {
  margin-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.fn,
.says,
.comment-awaiting-moderation {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: sans-serif, Arial;
  color: #2A2A2A;
  font-style: normal;
}
#cancel-comment-reply-link {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-family: sans-serif, Arial;
  color: #828282;
  text-decoration: none;
  -o-transition: .3s;
  -ms-transition: .3s;
  -moz-transition: .3s;
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
#cancel-comment-reply-link:hover {
  color: #2A2A2A;
}
.vcard {
  height: 74px;
  display: table;
}
.fn {
  padding-left: 10px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.comment-author {
  margin-bottom: 0.4em;
}
.commentmetadata {
  margin-bottom: 1.6em;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.says {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.comment-meta, comment-edit-link { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;}
```

```html
<ol class="comment-list">
     <li class="comment byuser comment-author-nadine bypostauthor even thread-even depth-1 parent" id="comment-2">
    <div id="div-comment-2" class="comment-body">
    <div class="comment-author vcard">
   <img alt='' src='http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/3facb3506c6c3f0d12efbf2f6d97a8e1?s=74&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g' srcset='http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/3facb3506c6c3f0d12efbf2f6d97a8e1?s=148&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g 2x' class='avatar avatar-74 photo' height='74' width='74' />   <cite class="fn">nadine</cite><span class="says"></span>  </div>
  
  <div class="comment-meta commentmetadata"><a href="http://backpackfamily.de/2016/05/beitrag-4/#comment-2">
   21. Mai 2016 um 19:50</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="comment-edit-link" href="http://backpackfamily.de/wp-admin/comment.php?action=editcomment&#038;c=2">(Bearbeiten)</a>  </div>

  <p>Hallo123</p>

  <div class="reply"><a rel='nofollow' class='comment-reply-link' href='http://backpackfamily.de/2016/05/beitrag-4/?replytocom=2#respond' onclick='return addComment.moveForm( "div-comment-2", "2", "respond", "33" )' aria-label='Antworte auf nadine'>Antworten</a></div>
    </div>
```

How can I get the date and the edit ("bearbeiten" in German) links next to the name so that it looks like:

name date edit

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for (https://jsfiddle.net/qqojuuow/1/)?

```
<ol class="comment-list">
  <li class="comment byuser comment-author-nadine bypostauthor even thread-even depth-1 parent" id="comment-2">
  <div id="div-comment-2" class="comment-body">
    <div class="comment-author vcard">
      <img alt='' src='http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/3facb3506c6c3f0d12efbf2f6d97a8e1?s=74&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g'  class='avatar avatar-74 photo' height='74' width='74' />         
      <div id="outer">
        <cite class="fn">nadine</cite><span class="says"></span>
        <div class="comment-meta commentmetadata"><a href="http://backpackfamily.de/2016/05/beitrag-4/#comment-2">21. Mai 2016 um 19:50</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="comment-edit-link" href="http://backpackfamily.de/wp-admin/comment.php?action=editcomment&#038;c=2">(Bearbeiten)</a>       </div>
      </div>
      <p>Hallo123</p>
      <div class="reply"><a rel='nofollow' class='comment-reply-link' href='http://backpackfamily.de/2016/05/beitrag-4/?replytocom=2#respond' onclick='return addComment.moveForm( "div-comment-2", "2", "respond", "33" )' aria-label='Antworte auf nadine'>Antworten</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

And css:

```
.commentlist {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}
.comment {
  margin-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.fn,
.says,
.comment-awaiting-moderation {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: sans-serif, Arial;
  color: #2A2A2A;
  font-style: normal;
}
#cancel-comment-reply-link {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-family: sans-serif, Arial;
  color: #828282;
  text-decoration: none;
  -o-transition: .3s;
  -ms-transition: .3s;
  -moz-transition: .3s;
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
#cancel-comment-reply-link:hover {
  color: #2A2A2A;
}
.vcard {
  height: 74px;
  display: table;
}
#outer {
  height: 74px;
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
  line-height: 74px;
}
.avatar {
  float: left;
}
p {
  display: block;
}
.comment-author {
  margin-bottom: 0.4em;
}
.commentmetadata {
  margin-bottom: 1.6em;
  display: inline;

}
.reply
```

---

To get rid of the #outer (https://jsfiddle.net/qqojuuow/3/):

```
.vcard {
  height: 74px;
  display: table;
  line-height: 74px;
}
.fn {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it should look like this. But the problem is that <div id="outer"> doesn't exist, because this is just the output. How can I solve it with given html?

Answer (score 1):

Why all this mess with `display: table-cell`? You could use `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: middle` to achieve what you want.

[Check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nnaphmrq/)

Comment: Looks fine, but it is just working for the last comment, all the other comments look like the one above.

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem you're facing. Here's another example with multiple <li> elements: https://jsfiddle.net/nnaphmrq/1/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xg0waxL7/ It's working there but what could be the problem? I can't figure it out

Answer (score 1):

Here it is without changing the HTML. I removed all of the "display:table-cell", and replaced it with one "display:inline-block" at the bottom. Please let me know if you have any questions.

CSS

```
.commentlist {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}
.comment {
  margin-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.fn,
.says,
.comment-awaiting-moderation {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: sans-serif, Arial;
  color: #2A2A2A;
  font-style: normal;
}
#cancel-comment-reply-link {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-family: sans-serif, Arial;
  color: #828282;
  text-decoration: none;
  -o-transition: .3s;
  -ms-transition: .3s;
  -moz-transition: .3s;
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
#cancel-comment-reply-link:hover {
  color: #2A2A2A;
}
.vcard {
  height: 74px;

}
.fn {
  padding-left: 10px;

  vertical-align: middle;
}
.comment-author {
  margin-bottom: 0.4em;
}
.commentmetadata {
  margin-bottom: 1.6em;


}

img, .inline{


display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

HTML

```
<ol class="comment-list">

        <div id="div-comment-2" class="comment-body">
            <div class="inline">
                <img alt='' src='http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/3facb3506c6c3f0d12efbf2f6d97a8e1?s=74&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g' srcset='http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/3facb3506c6c3f0d12efbf2f6d97a8e1?s=148&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g 2x' class='avatar avatar-74 photo' height='74' width='74'
                /> <cite class="fn">nadine</cite><span class="says"></span> </div>

            <div class="inline"><a href="http://backpackfamily.de/2016/05/beitrag-4/#comment-2">
            21. Mai 2016 um 19:50</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="comment-edit-link" href="http://backpackfamily.de/wp-admin/comment.php?action=editcomment&#038;c=2">(Bearbeiten)</a>
    </div>

            <p>Hallo123</p>

            <div class="reply"><a rel='nofollow' class='comment-reply-link' href='http://backpackfamily.de/2016/05/beitrag-4/?replytocom=2#respond' onclick='return addComment.moveForm( "div-comment-2", "2", "respond", "33" )' aria-label='Antworte auf nadine'>Antworten</a></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: This still looks like the old one :(

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xg0waxL7/ This is the fiddle, looks like it isn't displayed in wp